# Range of $\sin x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Given that $f(x)=\sin x$, $0\leq x \leq 180$.

Basically I know that the range of $\sin x$ is $-1\leq f(x) \leq 1$. 
How about this question ? Should I substitute the domain given to the function to get the range?

Comment: Hint: the range of angles $0°$ to $180°$ is the upper-half of the trigonometric circle.

Comment: that is not how the range is defined in the first place. It was the unit circle that is used to define the range of $\sin \theta$ as the $y$ coordinate of the point $P$ on the terminal side of a angle $\theta$ measured counter clockwise, and the highest and lowest point on the vertical line is $1,0$ giving the range $[0,1]$.

Comment: @KfSsOc: the upper-half circle doesn't reach negative sines.

Comment: I mean in general case.

Comment: @KfSsOc: that's already said by the OP.

Comment: my argument can still be applied .

Comment: what do you think?  Think about it for the function $f(x)=x$.  Change the domain, what happens to the range?

Comment: Hmmm, the OP deleted a comment asking if the domain affects the range.  I wasn't replying to you all, just FYI.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing the person asking the question doesn't know interval notation.  The range is $0 \leq x \leq 1$.  This is what everyone is talking about when they write $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,subbing the values would be  a great method, but an easier way it to just draw the graph since it is an elementary one. What you are really doing here is just shortening the domain. So the range will be [0,1]

Comment: So the range is what ?

Comment: @Mathxx [0,1] will be the range where 1 occurs at pi/2 and 0 is at the origin and pi.

Comment: @Mathxx: I guess that your personal research effort is below the standards for this site.